# How to use jQuery's flag to swap CSS display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks a drop down menu button (class .drop) the div with class .dropdown should `display: inline;` and when the drop down menu button is clicked again the div with class .dropdown should `display: none;` I am using the flag feature to achieve this result, but it does not do anything when clicked. It will work without the flag.

```
<script>
    $(".drop").on('click', function(){
        $('.dropdown').css('display', flag ? 'inline' : 'none' );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, can you please include your HTML as well?

Comment: where is the `flag` created

Comment: What is *"the flag feature"*?

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback function in **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

```
<script>
    $(".drop").on('click', function(){
        $('.dropdown').css('display', function(i,v){return v=='none' ? 'inline' : 'none' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav C. Balan, This works and performs the desired result, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to toggle between different CSS classes. You will, however, need to create the two classes. If you're toggling between two distinct classes you don't even need to keep track of the flag feature (I'm assuming you mean whether it's been toggled or not).

```js
$(".drop").on('click', function(){
  $('.dropdown').toggleClass('inline none');
});
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

What the `.toggleClass()` function does is add the particular class to the element if it doesn't have it and remove it if it's already part of the element.